# How to fix "using tensorflow backend" Keras import error?

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am currently starting Deep Learning with Keras. After I create a new Python file on Jupyter Notebook, I import Keras, only to find an error to appear. The error only occurs while importing Keras (As far as I know) and there is no error when I am importing other libraries such as numpy and pandas. Please help me fix this issue.

I have tried updating tensorflow, updating keras, using some code from other answers on Stack Overflow, but all was unsuccessful. I am currently trying "conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.12.0", but it is taking quite some time to run.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
```

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Comment: what is your numpy version.?

Comment: My numpy version is1.16.3

Comment: "using tensorflow backend" is an information message, not an error. The ImportError is caused because you have a broken numpy installation.

Comment: yeah I am trying to fix that. I uninstalled python and redownloaded it (3.6.0) I am now currently trying to uninstall anaconda but the command won't work